Replace the object returned by the endpoint with an object of a different type
ASP.NET 8, controllers.
I have a my type like a "Either": ResultOrUnprocessable<,>.
I have a method:
[HttpPost]
    public ResultOrUnprocessable<FileResult, SomeErrors> GetFileOrError()
    {
        return File([2, 3, 5, 6, 2], MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
    }

And IOutputFormatter. According to my idea, if the method “returned” FileResult (ResultOrUnprocessable.IsSuccess = true), then FileResult should become the return value and be processed by asp.net as if the method returned not ResultOrUnprocessable<,>, but FileResult.
public class ResultOrUnprocessableOutputFormatter : IOutputFormatter
{

    private static readonly PropertyInfo ObjectPropertyInfo;
    private static readonly PropertyInfo ObjectTypePropertyInfo;
    static ResultOrUnprocessableOutputFormatter()
    {
        var t = typeof(OutputFormatterCanWriteContext);
        ObjectPropertyInfo = t.GetProperty("Object") ?? throw new MissingMemberException();
        ObjectTypePropertyInfo = t.GetProperty("ObjectType") ?? throw new MissingMemberException();
    }
    
    public bool CanWriteResult(OutputFormatterCanWriteContext context)
    {
        if (context.Object is not IResultOrUnprocessable resultOrUnprocessable)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (resultOrUnprocessable.IsSuccess)
        {
            //here i replace ResultOrUnprocessable<,> with FileResult
            ObjectPropertyInfo.SetValue(context, resultOrUnprocessable.ResultObject);
            ObjectTypePropertyInfo.SetValue(context, resultOrUnprocessable.ResultObject?.GetType());
            
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public async Task WriteAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context)
    {
        if (context.Object is not IResultOrUnprocessable resultOrUnprocessable)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException();
        }
        
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        
        if (!resultOrUnprocessable.IsSuccess)
        {
            var serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(resultOrUnprocessable.UnprocessableInfoObject);
            response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity;
            response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Json;
            await response.WriteAsync(serialized);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new UnreachableException();
        }
    }
}

Program.cs:
services.AddControllers(options =>
        {
            options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<StringOutputFormatter>(); //so that json is returned and not plain text when I return string or int

            options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new ResultOrUnprocessableOutputFormatter());
            
        })

But FileResult is not returned as usual (application/octet-stream), but is returned as "application/json; charset=utf-8" with body:
{
    "filecontents": "AgMFBgI=",
    "contenttype": "application/octet-stream",
    "filedownloadname": "",
    "lastmodified": null,
    "entitytag": null,
    "enablerangeprocessing": false
}

How to replace ResultOrUnprocessable<FileResult, SomeErrors> with FileResult properly?
MVP: https://github.com/Lavshyak/ROUMVP

Can you please provide a full runnable [mre]? Also using static properties is not a good idea here. Also I don't see any actual usage of those static props.

https://github.com/Lavshyak/ROUMVP
